# Connecting Python and R scripts

Tags: python, r

I have 3 scripts: the 1st and the 3rd are written in R, and the 2nd in Python.

The output of the 1st script is the input of the 2nd script, and its output is the input of the 3rd one.

The inputs and outputs are search keywords or phrases.

For example, the output of the 1st script is `Hello`, then the 2nd turns the word to `olleH`, and the 3rd one converts the letters to uppercase: `OLLEH`.

My question is how can I connect those scripts and let them run automatically, without my intervention.

Comment: Look into the `reticulate` library in `R`.

Answer (score 0):

There are several options. You can either use R, Python or bash (or perhaps something third?). If you go the R way (since you have two scripts in R) you can run Python script using `system("python script.py inputs")` and then collect the result and pass it to the R script. This is assuming the script produces a file that can be input into the next script.

You could refactor R scripts to be functions for easier handling.

If you go the bash way, you would do

```
Rscript script1.R <parameters>
Python script2.py <parameters>
Rscript script3.R <parameters>
```

and each script should have an appropriate shebang (i.e. `#!/usr/bin/Rscript`).